# Filtering Fonts from NSFontPanel?

Tags: cocoa, delegates, filtering, nsfontmanager

According to the documentation, you should set an <NSFontManagerDelegate> to the shared instance of NSFontManager. The delegate should implement a method

```
- (BOOL) fontManager:(id)sender willIncludeFont:(NSString *)fontName;
```

which will then be called repeatedly. Unfortunately, there is no documentation of <NSFontManagerDelegate> available, and in fact the protocol is missing. All the same, I created an instance of NSObject that implements the method mentioned above, and set it as a delegate of NSFontManager. Unfortunately, the method is never called. After some googling, I learned that fontManager:willIncludeFont: is deprecated since OS X 10.3.

Is there any alternative? What should I do if my application only supports mono-spaced fonts?

Comment: subclass `NSFontManager`, override `- (NSArray *)collectionNames`, return a list of font collections.[\[1\]][1]


  [1]: https://alpha.app.net/destroyo/post/4981273

Comment: OK, thanks! Yet another subclass... *sigh*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

subclass `NSFontManager`, override `- (NSArray *)collectionNames`, return a list of font collections.[[1]](https://alpha.app.net/destroyo/post/4981273)